# What are Inters/Intex/Supers?

Tags: futures

The CME Group website, under the `Margins` tab, has a page titled "Inters/Intex/Supers". See [here](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/e-micro-gold_performance_bonds.html?marginsTab=INTER) for example.

What are Inters/Intex/Supers?

Comment: You plan to trade gold futures?

Comment: Potentially, yes! Those E-micro are just about affordable. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `Inter` and `Super` refer to the mix of products within the contract.  I'm not sure about `Intex`.  See this [Investopedia page](http://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/series-3/studyguide/chapter7/spread-trading.asp) for some more info.

`Intra`-commodity spreads (which have a separate web page) are what typical traders mean when they talk about a "spread product" -- i.e. a `calendar spread`, where you trade two (or maybe more) different expiration dates for a commodity at the same time.  For example, you might want to simultaneously (a) sign 1 contract to buy gold in April and (b) sign 1 contract to sell gold in May.  You can do that by dealing in calendar spreads.

`Inter`-commodity spreads typically share the same calendar month but combine different products.  Usually those products are related -- say, all in the "Energy" realm -- such that it's common for people to want to buy and sell them together.  (Other times the connection between the products might be harder to see at first blush until you get deep into the data.)

Just by inspection it seems that the `Super` spreads involve more products and/or more due dates, and I still don't really know about `Intex`.  The CME Glossary page has a lot of info, but not much concerning their own jargon ...